# insert hyphen between <rt> element in <ruby> annotation in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using `<ruby>` annotation in HTML to display Vietnamese pronunciations of Chinese characters. For example:

[image: situation]

```css
ruby {
  font: inherit;
  letter-spacing: 3em;
  /* to have more space for annotations, word-spacing doesnt work for me */
  user-select: none;
  /* prevent text selection of Chinese character */
}

rt {
  font: inherit;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  user-select: text;
  /* allow text selection */
  text-align: left;
  /* prevent default center align */
}
```

```html
<ruby>
 是<rt>Thị</rt>
 故<rt>cố</rt>
 空<rt>không</rt>
 中<rt>trung</rt>
</ruby>
```

Now I want to insert an hyphen between some Vietnamese words (`<rt>` elements) (*the reason is linguistically some words often come together, so adding an hyphen to group them together to improve readability*). Basically the **expected result** is something like this :

[image: expected]

Right now what I've been doing is adding a space and attach the hyphen to it :

```html
<ruby>
    是<rt>Thị</rt>
    故<rt>cố</rt>
    空<rt>không</rt>
    &nbsp;<rt>-</rt>
    中<rt>trung</rt>
</ruby>
```

The problem is that add too much spacing between Chinese characters (I've already increased `letter-spacing`)

[image: actual]

The expected hyphen should:

- not add extra space between 2 Chinese characters
- be centrally aligned between 2 Vietnamese words (i.e. `<rt>` elements) as much as possible
- be in a `<rt>` element to be selectable/copyable (I've set `user-select`)

If possible, please provide me a solution with simple HTML, CSS, JS (jQuery possible but no more, *it's just a small project for fun during this coronavirus confinement* )

Comment: Sounds like you want to *decrease* `letter-spacing`...?

Comment: well... may be not, because sometimes the words in `<rt>` get a bit long, that value of `letter-spacing` is somewhat the smallest I found after many trials

Comment: I was thinking you'd decrease it specifically for the space and hyphen. Maybe wrap it in a `span` with a class you could control... Or maybe wrap the hyphenated phrase... Anyway, just thinking out loud; feel free to ignore :).

Comment: not a bad idea then. thanks! I'll try it